# Netbeans + GlassFish: package javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, netbeans, glassfish

Установил Netbeans 12.0. Сервер GlassFish 5.1.0. Создаю сервлет и среда ругается javax.servlet does not exist. Я думал, что этот пакет автоматически подтянется из GlassFish, но, что-то не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: GlassFish]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить библиотеку самостоятельно. В ***Properties*** вашего проекта выбрать вкладку ***Libraries***, далее жмите ***Add Library*** или ***Add JAR***, там выбирайте подходящий jar и ***ok*** (например \NetBeans-12.0\netbeans\enterprise\modules\ext\javaee-api-8.0.jar или \GlassFish_Server\mq\lib\jakarta.servlet-api.jar).